# Check whitespace in a Python string

Tags: python

Why do I always get `YES!!!`? I need to return `NO!!!` if the string contain a whitespace (newline, tap, space)

```
user = "B B"

if user.isspace():
    print("NO!!!")
else:
    print("YES!!!")
```

Comment: `user = B B` will be SyntaxError, invalid syntax

Comment: The `isspace` function only returns `True` for strings that contain nothing but whitespace.

Comment: Then how can I check if there is a space in a string?

Comment: @Digi_B use `if user.find(' ') >=0 :`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def tt(w): 
    if ' ' in w: 
       print 'space' 
    else: 
       print 'no space' 

>>   tt('b ')
>> space
>>  tt('b b')
>> space
>>  tt('bb')
>> no space
```

I am in train, sorry for not explaining.. cannot type much..

Comment: Thanks. But When I run this with "B B" I get "theres space" just as I want. However, when I run "B " I get no space. Why?

Comment: Try `'B'.split() == 'B '.split()` If `'B '` should be considered to have a space, this solution is wrong.

Comment: @gamedesigner edited the answer. Now it works for both cases.

Comment: Does not work for a `\t` or `\n` or any [whitespace character](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.3.0/ucd/PropList.txt) other than ASCII 0x20 (a normal space bar character). The OP stated any whitespace, including a tab or newline

Answer (score 9):

You are using [`isspace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) which says

**str.isspace()**

> Return true if there are only whitespace characters in the string and there is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

Comment: While a totally valid explanation, this does not show how to fix.

Comment: Please note: `isspace` does not return true for `None` or `''` . The equivalent of `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` in .NET would be `not s or s.isspace()`

Answer (score 6):

Here is a neat method that illustrates the flexibility of list comprehensions. It is a helper method that checks to see if a given string contains any whitespace.

Code:

```
import string
def contains_whitespace(s):
    return True in [c in s for c in string.whitespace]
```

Example:

```
>>> contains_whitespace("BB")
False
>>> contains_whitespace("B B")
True
```

This can, of course, be extended to check if any string contains an element in any set (rather than just whitespace). The previous solution is a neat, short solution, but some may argue it is hard to read and less Pythonic than something like:

```
def contains_whitespace(s):
    for c in s:
        if c in string.whitespace:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: `True in ...` is equal to `any(...)`.

Comment: To expand on ArtOfWarfare's comment, the more elegant solution would perhaps be to use a generator expression with `any()`, for example: `return any(c in s for c in string.whitespace)`. A quick benchmark on my box shows that `any()` runs slightly faster under CPython 3.6 than the list comprehension (you mileage may vary, depending on the typical format of the string you expect).

Comment: Yes. `any()` will return on the first occurence of something evaluating to True! So it does not create the full list first.

Comment: This is the best answer, considering whitespace is more than just spaces. Although it should be updated to use `any()`, considering the efficiency improvement mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are looking for more than just a simple `' '` where you could use `' ' in tgt` you can use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
for s in ('B ', 'B B', 'B\nB', 'BB'):
    print repr(s), any(c.isspace() for c in s)
```

Prints:

```
'B ' True
'B B' True
'B\nB' True
'BB' False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
user = 'B B'
for x in user:
    if x.isspace():
        print("no")
    else:print("yes")
```

you need to loop over it to check for all element, but the above code will not work as you expect.

use a helper function:

```
def space(text):
    if ' ' in text:
        return True
    else: return False
```

demo:

```
>>> ' ' in 'B B'
True
>>> ' ' in 'BB'
False
```

use `in` to check

if you want to use `isspace`:

```
def space(text):
    for x in text:
        if x.isspace():
            return True
    return False
```

Instead of returning True or False you can return Desired string too:

```
>>> def space(text):
...     if ' ' in text:
...         return " yes Spaces"
...     else: return " No Spaces"
... 
>>> space('B B')
' yes Spaces'
>>> space('BB')
' No Spaces'
```

Comment: This would display the result for each character. I only want to display "no" if there is a whitespace and "yes" if there is not.

Comment: yep , i am making a helper to make it OP better to understand

Answer (score 2):

There are already good answers to your question. Here is a way to get total number of spaces (or any other char) in string

```
>>> "I contain 3 spaces".count(" ")
3
>>> "Nospaces".count(" ")
0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split` to check if a string contains spaces:

```
>>> ''.split()
[]
>>> '  '.split()
[]
>>> 'BB'.split()
['BB']
>>> ' B '.split()
['B']
>>> 'B B'.split()
['B', 'B']
```

So you can check as

```
def hasspace(x):
    if x:
        s = x.split()
        return len(s) == 1 and x == s[0]
    return False
```

If you are only trying to check for whole words in the string (i.e., you are not worried about surrounding spaces that could be removed by `x.strip()`), the condition `x == s[0]` is no longer necessary. The check becomes a single statement:

```
def hasspace(x):
    return x and len(x.split()) == 1
```

Now you can do

```
if hasspace(user):
    print("NO!!!")
else:
    print("YES!!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can loop through the string and check for whitespaces.

> make a variable 'is_there_whitespace'

> as its value, give it the length of whitespce found

> If its greater than 0 boom you got white space.

```py
user = "B B"

is_there_whitespace = len([True for x in user if x.isspace()])

print(f"Is there white space? {is_there_whitespace>0}.")
print(f"Amount of white spaces found:{is_there_whitespace}")
```

```sh
> Is there white space? True.
> Amount of white space found:1.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: a<br>
Out[1]: ' b\t\n'

In [2]: (' ' in a)or('\t' in a)or('\n' in a)<br>
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

To efficiently check if there is any whitespace character in a given string:

```
any(map(str.isspace, mystr))
```

Also, as [previously answered by dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26987748/), another way to write it is:

```
any(char.isspace() for char in mystr)
```